# Need help optimizing this simple query

Tags: postgresql, date, indexing

My end goal is to optimize my query using indexes, but I'm having trouble adding the right index. Everything I've tried results in the same cost in the Explain diagram, and no indication that it's even using any indexes.

I have two tables:

- `event` that has two `date` columns: `start_date` and `end_date` (can be null).
- `fiscal_date` that has:

  - two `date` columns `start_date` and `end_date` (cannot be null)
  - a `fiscal_year` column of type `char(4)`
  - a `fiscal_quarter` column of type `char(1)`

There's another table `address` that's just a one-to-one with a foreign key in `event`. There's no indexes on it save the public key.

I have a query that I can't change that figures out what fiscal quarter and year the event **starts** in:

```
SELECT
    e.*, 
    (select 'Q' || fd.fiscal_quarter || ' FY' || fd.fiscal_year
        from fiscal_date fd
        where e.start_date between fd.start_date and fd.end_date
        limit 1) as fiscal_quarter_year,

    (select 'Q' || fd.fiscal_quarter
        from fiscal_date fd
        where e.start_date between fd.start_date and fd.end_date
        limit 1) as fiscal_quarter,

    (select 'FY' || fd.fiscal_year
        from fiscal_date fd
        where e.start_date between fd.start_date and fd.end_date
        limit 1) as fiscal_year,

    a.street1, a.street2, a.street3, a.city, a.state, a.country, a.postal_code

FROM event AS e
LEFT OUTER JOIN address a ON e.address_id=a.address_id;
```

Here's an EXPLAIN of the query (notice all the expensive seq scans on the left):

[image: explain of query]

As requested, here's the output of `explain analyze`:

```
 Hash Left Join  (cost=115.78..2846.64 rows=1649 width=5087) (actual time=18.334..134.279 rows=1649 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (e.address_id = a.address_id)
   ->  Seq Scan on event e  (cost=0.00..323.49 rows=1649 width=5031) (actual time=0.223..19.808 rows=1649 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=68.68..68.68 rows=3768 width=60) (actual time=17.797..17.797 rows=3768 loops=1)
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 248kB
         ->  Seq Scan on address a  (cost=0.00..68.68 rows=3768 width=60) (actual time=0.004..9.071 rows=3768 loops=1)
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.49 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.011..0.014 rows=1 loops=1649)
           ->  Seq Scan on fiscal_date fd  (cost=0.00..1.46 rows=3 width=28) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=1649)
                 Filter: (($0 >= start_date) AND ($0 <= end_date))
   SubPlan 2
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.48 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.012 rows=1 loops=1649)
           ->  Seq Scan on fiscal_date fd  (cost=0.00..1.43 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=1649)
                 Filter: (($1 >= start_date) AND ($1 <= end_date))
   SubPlan 3
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.48 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.010..0.012 rows=1 loops=1649)
           ->  Seq Scan on fiscal_date fd  (cost=0.00..1.43 rows=3 width=20) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=1649)
                 Filter: (($2 >= start_date) AND ($2 <= end_date))
 Total runtime: 138.008 ms
```

I've tried adding indexes to `event` that index the start and end dates (both and individually), adding an index to `fiscal_date`'s date columns, but nothing seems to be reducing the cost calculation of this query.

How do I optimize this query, or isn't it possible?

Comment: Please post the output of explain analyze <query>, it is very difficult to draw much conclusion from the information provided. A general tip is to use joins over sub-queries when possible, it usually performs better.

Comment: cool explain, what makes that?  what does it mean?  is there a query you left out?  the query you show selects all of the rows from event, so an index isn't going to help.

Comment: @greg It's made in the [pgAdmin](http://pgadmin.org/) tool.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I find the plain text output from `explain analyze` *much* more informative (and easier to understand) than the graphical display

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It sure contains a lot more information. PgAdmin's is easier to read without practice though, so it has some utility for new users.

Comment: @BjörnNilsson Agreed that we need `explain analyze`. The use of subqueries here will be because of the need to `limit` the result.

Comment: @amphetamachine Your query is buggy - you use `limit` without `order by`, so PostgreSQL can return whichever matching row it happens to find first.

Comment: @BjörnNilsson I've added the explain analyze output.

Comment: @CraigRinger Like I said, I can't change the query, so I can't do anything about its bugginess. Also, I doubt that has anything whatsoever to do with optimizing this query.

Comment: Did you try an index on `fiscal_date(start_date, end_date)`?

Comment: @amphetamachine Agreed that it's not particularly relevant for optimisation. I was just pointing out the problem. On a side note, I'm getting *so* sick of environments where people can't change the query, can't update PostgreSQL, can't install anything, don't have Internet access, and want a magic fix that doesn't actually change anything at all. You have my sympathy if you're in such an environment.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,  so your problem isn't the fiscal date sequential scans, the number of rows are so few that sequential scan is probably the correct thing to do.  You probably want Index on address._id  on both tables. 
If adress_is is the primary key of adress table it already is indexed.

Also, just to be sure,  run vacuum full and vacuum analyze on all tables.

EDIT:
The performance seems really bad considering there are so few rows (under 10000 is nothing). Are the tables really big or is the hardware ancient? If not you should probably take a serious look at the configuration (working mem etc)